# Is there a risk of a bootstrap problem when using NTS?

Tags: tls, ntp

Reading up on the NTP protocol wikipedia page as well as blog posts about NTS, it appears like NTS uses TLS to start the encrypted connection. From what I understand, TLS might not work properly if there is a significant difference in time between the server and client. If so, doesn't using NTS mean that if the client system time is misconfigured, the NTS call might fail because the TLS connection can't be established?

Answer (score 1):

The thing about **TLS 1.3** is that both parties **do not** need to be within a single timeframe to be performing the handshake, or share time-related information at the start. **TLS 1.1** & **TLS 1.2** however, had a time element in its Client Hello message

**TLS 1.1** & **TLS 1.2** Client Hello Message,

```
Structure of this message:

      The client hello message includes a random structure, which is
      used later in the protocol.

      struct {
         uint32 gmt_unix_time;
         opaque random_bytes[28];
      } Random;
```

Under the `gmt_unix_time` variable as seen above, here are the documentation for [**TLS 1.1** Client Hello Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.1.2) & [**TLS 1.2** Client Hello Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2)

> The current time and date in standard UNIX 32-bit
> format (seconds since the midnight starting Jan 1, 1970, GMT,
> ignoring leap seconds) according to the sender's internal clock.
> **Clocks are not required to be set correctly** by the basic TLS
> Protocol; higher-level or application protocols may define
> additional requirements.

With the above paragraph supports the fact that even with the time involved, it is merely used in a way to randomized the message.

**TLS 1.3** Client Hello Message, here is the documentation for [TLS 1.3 Client Hello Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.1.2)

```
Structure of this message:

      uint16 ProtocolVersion;
      opaque Random[32];

      uint8 CipherSuite[2];    /* Cryptographic suite selector */

      struct {
          ProtocolVersion legacy_version = 0x0303;    /* TLS v1.2 */
          Random random;
          opaque legacy_session_id<0..32>;
          CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
          opaque legacy_compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
          Extension extensions<8..2^16-1>;
      } ClientHello;
```

The variable `gmt_unix_time` has been removed in **TLS 1.3**

[image]

## Despite [**NTS**](https://blog.apnic.net/2019/11/08/network-time-security-new-ntp-authentication-mechanism/) using **TLS 1.2** and **TLS 1.3**, initial time would not be an issue!

Comment: I see. And having client time set in the 1970s won't be a problem for TLS certificates that are signed and expire 50 years later?

Comment: That time used in these hello flags is not a deciding factor on the expiry date on these certificates, merely just for the initial authentication transaction. The certificate will be updated by the NTS with the current time, local client configuration would not matter. Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought TLS certificate expiration checks happen on the client side? Server sends their public key certificate over the wire, browser checks it's not expired or revoked and that it resolves to a rood certificate. Does certificate validation simply not care that a certificate has been issued in the future?

Comment: The cert is valid for a period of time (a couple of years at best). Your client will validate the time on the cert against their own time. You client will most likely thing its all good, but actually its months back from the current time and he will find out soon from the CA,  access/authentication will not happen, a renewal of cert will be in the talks and maybe a change of time for the client (NTP/NTS), do take note that this is way after the initial handshake! :)

Comment: That's it though: suppose the client is configured to use NTS. It can't negotiate NTS because the time doesn't match, so it can't automatically update the local time so the time would match. Does NTS work if there is a time mismatch that's enough to interrupt TLS negotiation?

Comment: The client will be able to negotiate with NTS, the client does not need to be in the current time to get the current time! The initial handshake of the TLS can be & will be done with or without current time. From there on, TLS passes over to NTS for key establishment. Once the NTS-KE server connection is secured (still no time information), the client is then able to communicate with NTP and followed by syncing of time. At this point, the packets have way more overhead than a regular NTP packet without NTS.